# Python 3 Base64 decode messing up newline characters

Tags: python, base64, decoding

I'm trying to decode a base64 multi-line file through the standard python library, however only the first line gets decoded, and the rest gets dumped for no reason.

Why is this?

The file before it gets encoded (what I'm trying to achieve after decoding):

> dataFile.dat
>
> VERSION: BenWin+ Version: 3.0.12.1[CR]
>
> [CR][LF]
>
> CREATED: 01 September 2016 12:56:27 PM[CR]
>
> [CR][LF]
>
> TIME CODE: 0x907e0, 0x10004, 0x38000c, 0x242001b[CR]
>
> [CR][LF]
>
> ...

[CR] and [LF] are the character codes for Carriage Return (\r) and Line Feed (\n) respectively

I base64 encode the file using base64.b64encode and want to decode it later. Here is my code snippet.

```
encodedData = b'VkVSU0lPTjogQmVuV2luKyBWZXJzaW9uOiAzLjAuMTIuMQo=Cg==Q1JFQVRFRDogMDEgU2VwdGVtYmVyIDIwMTYgMTI6NTY6MjcgUE0KCg==VElNRSBDT0RFOiAweDkwN2UwLCAweDEwMDA0LCAweDM4MDAwYywgMHgyNDIwMDFiCg==Cg=='

data = base64.b64decode(encodedData)
print(data)
```

Which returns

> b'VERSION: BenWin+ Version: 3.0.12.1\n'

Thanks in advance.
Using Python 3.5

Comment: Are you Base64-encoding it yourself?

Comment: If I could change the endline characters through regex, would changing it to be exclusively \n or \r help? Or perhaps getting rid of the empty lines?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, should I be putting additional options in the encoding operation?

Comment: You should not be concatenating the individual Base64-encoded strings together like that. I'll post an answer shortly that shows how to encode & decode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are encoding each line separately and then joining those encoded strings together. A Base-64 encoded string may end in padding characters, and when the decoder sees those padding characters it assumes that's the end of the valid data, so any following data is ignored.

Here's how to Base64 encode multi-line text in Python 3. First, we need to convert the Unicode text to bytes. Then we Base64 encode all those bytes in one go. To decode, we reverse the process: first Base64 decode, then decode the resulting bytes to a Unicode string. Notice that the `\r` and `\n` have been preserved properly.

```
import base64

s = 'VERSION: BenWin+ Version: 3.0.12.1\r\r\nCREATED: 01 September 2016 12:56:27 PM\r\r\nTIME CODE: 0x907e0, 0x10004, 0x38000c, 0x242001b\r\r\n'
print(s)

b = base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf8'))
print(b)

z = base64.b64decode(b).decode('utf8')
print(repr(z))
```

**output**

```
VERSION: BenWin+ Version: 3.0.12.1
CREATED: 01 September 2016 12:56:27 PM
TIME CODE: 0x907e0, 0x10004, 0x38000c, 0x242001b

b'VkVSU0lPTjogQmVuV2luKyBWZXJzaW9uOiAzLjAuMTIuMQ0NCkNSRUFURUQ6IDAxIFNlcHRlbWJlciAyMDE2IDEyOjU2OjI3IFBNDQ0KVElNRSBDT0RFOiAweDkwN2UwLCAweDEwMDA0LCAweDM4MDAwYywgMHgyNDIwMDFiDQ0K'
'VERSION: BenWin+ Version: 3.0.12.1\r\r\nCREATED: 01 September 2016 12:56:27 PM\r\r\nTIME CODE: 0x907e0, 0x10004, 0x38000c, 0x242001b\r\r\n'
```

Comment: Awesome, when you said concatenating the encoded strings is wrong I immediately thought it could be some padding problem. Thanks for explaining how to fix it :)

Comment: No worries, @Jessie! Be aware that there are a couple of different "flavours" of base64 encoding, the base64 module docs explain the differences. These days, we mostly need to use a version of base64 that's suitable in a URL.